# Why Celery copy task instance?

Tags: python, copy, celery

I would like to understand this.

When Celery worker starts it creates an instance of the task only once (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation). Then, when work comes, Celery, looks like, copies this instance and do the work.

Why copy? Why not new instance? What kind of problem solves this approach? Is there is some kind of pattern?

Comment: Where are you seeing that it copies the instance? The docs you link to say no such thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, i just assumed.

Comment: So you're asking why Celery does something that you have no evidence that it actually does?

Comment: I can not call the line number where this is going, but I see no other way to provide encapsulation.

Comment: Look, the documentation clearly and explicitly states that it instantiates it only once and that therefore state is shared between requests. Why, then, would you think that there is any kind of encapsulation?

Comment: Create TestTask class with propery `i`. Increment `i` in `run` method every seconds and print the result. Then run two tasks and you will see that `task1.i` and `task 2.i` is different. But worker calls `TestTask.__init__()` only once. https://yadi.sk/d/C-33vwIYkkBHB

Comment: I have no idea what you just linked to; if you have code, post it in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96244/discussion-between-hloroform-and-daniel-roseman).